# compare two xml files using xslt/ c#

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

I have two xml's . Need to read these two and create new xml with only different elements

Hello experts,
i am kinda new to thisstuff, i wanted to know how to compare two xml files using  C#/xmlunit2.0 and display another xml file only 
with the differences in the xml file:

xml1:

```
  <ORDERS>
     <ORDER>
      <ORDERNUM>979793524</ORDERNUM>
      <TIES>
        <TIE>
          <TIENUMBER>1</TIENUMBER>
          <ITEMS>
             <ITEM>
              <ITEMNUMBER>KF3P2</ITEMNUMBER>
              <ITEMQTY>1</ITEMQTY>
            </ITEM>
            <ITEM>
              <ITEMNUMBER>60RD2</ITEMNUMBER>
              <ITEMQTY>1</ITEMQTY>
            </ITEM>
          </ITEMS>
        </TIE>
      </TIES>
    </ORDER>
  </ORDERS>
```

XML2:

```
   <ORDERS>
    <ORDER>
      <ORDERNUM>979793524</ORDERNUM>
      <TIES>
        <TIE>
          <TIENUMBER>1</TIENUMBER>
          <ITEMS>
            <ITEM>
              <ITEMNUMBER>60RD2</ITEMNUMBER>
              <ITEMQTY>1</ITEMQTY>
            </ITEM>
            <ITEM>
              <ITEMNUMBER>KF3P2</ITEMNUMBER>
              <ITEMQTY>25</ITEMQTY>
            </ITEM>
          </ITEMS>
        </TIE>
      </TIES>
    </ORDER>
  </ORDERS>

  Expected Output:

  <ORDERNUM>979793524</ORDERNUM>
   <ITEMNUMBER>KF3P2</ITEMNUMBER>
   <ITEMQTY>25</ITEMQTY>
```

Comment: I don't think XSLT is the right tool for this task; but maybe you will find a C# library that does exactly this

Comment: A simple approach might be, canonicalize both xmls (for instance, with `xmllint --format`) and then compare it with standard diff - but this can produce false negatives

Comment: Will both files have the same order numbers, and will each order have the same item numbers so it is only the quantity differs? If not, and orders and items can exist in one file but both the other, how would you present the results? Thanks!

Comment: HI Tim both the files will have same order numbers and order numbers will have same item numbers

Answer (score 2):

It's a challenging task and there's no generic (i.e. vocabulary-independent) solution, partly because only you know what's significant in your data and what isn't - for example in this case it seems order of ITEM elements is irrelevant (which wouldn't be the case if you were comparing two journal articles). There's presumably some reasoning behind not regarding the presence of TIEQTY in one document and its absence from the other as a significant difference, and for including ORDERNUM but not TIENUMBER in the result.

One approach to this is:

(a) flatten the data to a particular level, say ITEM, so significant properties of the ITEM container (e.g. ORDERNUM) become properties of the ITEM.

(b) for each ITEM, compute a distinguishing signature as a string, such that two items have different signatures if they are different.

(c) use grouping to group ITEMs across the two files by signature.

(d) output (some representation of) those ITEMS where the group size is 1.

This can all be done conveniently with XSLT 2.0, or even better using [`xsl:merge`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#merge-instruction) in XSLT 3.0.